# Watt to amp-hours of AC device

Tags: ampere-hour

Please help me understand [the calculation in this table](https://engineerswhovanlife.com/van-electrical-system/#elementor-toc__heading-anchor-8). The writer has a 12V batery connected to a 12V/110V inverter connected to standard house-hold AC appliances.

The calculation for the 1000W induction stovetop is:

1000W/12/0.85=98. 98*0.75h=73.5Ah (where 0.85 is 15% power conversion loss.)

Shouldn't it be 1000W/110V/0.85=10.7. 10.7*0.75h=8Ah?

Comment: Your question alone shows your misunderstanding, it should be "Watts of an AC device to amp-hours of a battery", and there you would have an answer to your confusion.

Comment: Note that AC power in North America is 120V not 110V.  It hasn't been 110V since Vietnam. It matters on this kind of calc, since it's 9%!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were running the stove-top from AC you would use 120 V to figure the current, but they are calculating the Ah drawn from the battery so they use 12 V.

If you drew 8 A from a 12 V battery for an hour that would only be 96 Watt-hours, hardly what you'd expect for a stove.

So, you need 1000 W for the stove, to get 1000 W at 12 V the current would be
$$ \frac{1000W}{12V} = 83.333A$$
Running the stove for 45 minutes it would use
$$83.333A\times0.75h=62.5Ah$$
Accounting for 85% efficiency
$$\frac{62.5Ah}{0.85}=75.53Ah$$
Which agrees with their calculation.

Comment: Errata: North American AC power is 120V.  The calc should be **83.33** A *multiplied by* 0.75 H.  I would fix it but don't know the markup language :)

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Fixed the formula. I said 110 because that's what was in the original question.